# Heroku failed to connect using Jenkins

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, jenkins, heroku, deployment

I have an application currently deployed to Heroku that I'm trying to connect to Jenkins but I'm getting this error

```
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'Heroku'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://git.heroku.com/myApp.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:862)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1129)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1160)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1276)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:560)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:485)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1735)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress https://git.heroku.com/myApp.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/Heroku/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: remote: !   WARNING:
remote: !   Do not authenticate with username and password using git.
remote: !   Run `heroku login` to update your credentials, then retry the git command.
remote: !   See documentation for details: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#http-git-authentication
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git.heroku.com/myApp.git/'
```

I've run `heroku login` and when I run `heroku apps --all` it lists all of my current apps and my username, confirming a successful login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which login/local account your Jenkins is running.

If it is not running with the *same* account, it would not benefit from your successful `heroku login` command.

Comment: I'm sorry I think I'm lost. How can I see which Heroku account my Jenkins is linked to?

Comment: @Naji This is not about the heroku account, but about the local user account used for running Jenkins itself. Unless everything is running on an AWS instance, as I realize reading your deleted question https://stackoverflow.com/q/48123800/6309

Comment: oh yes I remember now, Jenkins creates a local user account... do you know how I go about accessing that in AWS? Or where you can direct me to find out?

Comment: @Naji Actually, why not create a first job whose only step is to do an heroku login: that would persists the login for the local Jenkins account. Then your other job might succeed.

Comment: If you're not busy, would you start a chat with me?

Comment: Sure let me add some comment in order to trigger the chat notification

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162645/discussion-between-vonc-and-naji).